# how can I slow down a video (I lower pitch by a semitone) with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an old black and white film with audio that was recorded on a phonograph and the playback speed of the audio is a semi-tone higher than it should be.  How can I process this video with ffmpeg and slow down BOTH the video and audio together, bringing the audio down a half step (semi-tone) while keeping the video in sync?

I have tried filters like `asetrate`, `setpts`, `atempo`, etc and although I could change the pitch of the audio, the video became badly out of sync with the audio.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" -an output.mp4

0.5 is the ratio

Comment: This results in no audio.